# How to export AWS Crawler configuration to JSON (or similar) and check in to source control?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-crawler, aws-glue

My team has developed multiple crawlers in AWS Glue to scan data and catalog the schema. I'm hoping check these crawlers into our source control, but am unable to find a way to do so. Am I able to export Crawlers as JSON or XML to be able to check in that file?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the JSON by running the aws cli command. For example to get all crawlers you can run:

`aws glue get-crawlers`

To get a specific crawler you can run:

`aws glue get-crawler --name`